# Publish event is getting triggered before producer is ready

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka

I have written a node module to connect to Kafka.

kafka-connect.js

```
var kafka = require('kafka-node');

var Producer = kafka.Producer,
    client = new kafka.Client(),
    producer = new Producer(client);

module.exports = {
    producer
};
```

KafkaService.js

```
const {producer} = require('./kafka-connect');

producer.on('error', function (err) {
    console.log('Producer is in error state');
    console.log(err);
});
producer.on('ready', function () {
    console.log('Producer is ready');
});

const KafkaService = {
     sendRecord: (kafkaTopic, data, callback = (err, data) => console.log(err)) => {
        var sendingData = {};
        sendingData.event_data = JSON.stringify(data);
        sendingData.event_type = 6;
        const record = [
            {
                topic: kafkaTopic,
                messages: sendingData,
                partition : 0
            }
        ];
        producer.send(record, callback);
     }
};

module.exports = {
    KafkaService
};
```

Now I am using these two to publish data to Kafka. Following is the code to do so:

```
const {KafkaService} = require('../kafka/KafkaService');

const {newOrder} = require('../objs/newOrderEvent');

KafkaService.sendRecord("incentive_order_data", newOrder);
```

But running this file gives error :

```
{ BrokerNotAvailableError: Broker not available
    at new BrokerNotAvailableError (/Users/rajat.mishra/self/nodekafka/node_modules/kafka-node/lib/errors/BrokerNotAvailableError.js:11:9)
    at Client.loadMetadataForTopics (/Users/rajat.mishra/self/nodekafka/node_modules/kafka-node/lib/client.js:389:15)
    at Client.send (/Users/rajat.mishra/self/nodekafka/node_modules/kafka-node/lib/client.js:562:10)
    at /Users/rajat.mishra/self/nodekafka/node_modules/kafka-node/lib/client.js:241:10
    at /Users/rajat.mishra/self/nodekafka/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:473:16
    at iteratorCallback (/Users/rajat.mishra/self/nodekafka/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1064:13)
    at /Users/rajat.mishra/self/nodekafka/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:969:16
    at buildRequest (/Users/rajat.mishra/self/nodekafka/node_modules/kafka-node/lib/client.js:257:24)
    at /Users/rajat.mishra/self/nodekafka/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3110:16
    at eachOfArrayLike (/Users/rajat.mishra/self/nodekafka/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1069:9) message: 'Broker not available' }
Producer is ready
```

Apparently, publish method is getting called before the producer is ready. I am not able to come up with a solution to this. One way is to bring Promises in the picture, but that is just my hypothesis, exact method might be different.

Comment: I thought this error comes from `producer.on('ready'` by itself. The broker should be available in either case, if not its this error

Comment: Nopes. The error is due to sendRecord getting called before the producer is ready.

Answer (score 0):

You're not waiting for the producer to be ready.

You'll need to do this

```
producer.on('ready', function () {
    console.log('Producer is ready');

   // send data here 
});
```

Comment: But how should I do that? I am exporting the function from the file.  How do I prevent that?

Comment: I would suggest removing `KafkaService.js`, and putting all that code in your main file until you get things working and can refactor later